# EditorForModel() not working

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, razor

I am using EditorForModel() to populate Data

Index Method :

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    SampleDbContext db = new SampleDbContext();
    return View(db.Employees.ToList());
}
```

Index View :

```
@model IEnumerable<MultipleRowsDemo.Models.Employee>

<div style="font-family:Aria">

@using (Html.BeginForm())
{ 
    <table border="1">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>
                    Select
                </th>
                <th>
                    Name
                </th>
                <th>
                    Email
                </th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        @Html.EditorForModel()
        </tbody>
    </table>
}

</div>
```

but it is not working. It displays data like

> 123 Select     Name    Email

I read similar posts

[EditorForModel and DisplayForModel do not work then passing class model within class model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13705681/editorformodel-and-displayformodel-do-not-work-then-passing-class-model-within-c)

It is suggested not use complex properties. I don't have one.

Another one is.

[Displaying entities data with EditorForModel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16320607/displaying-entities-data-with-editorformodel)

It suggested to use

```
@using(Html.BeginForm())
{
...
}
```

I already have this.

Comment: I can't test this right now but I don't think `EditoForModel` should work out of the box for an `IEnumerable` of a complex object (i.e. an instance of a certain class you created). Leave this code as is and Create a `Employee.cshtml` in your `Views/Shared/EditorTemplates` folder (create the EditorTemplatesFolder it's not there by default) but if you're using Areas put the file in `YourAreaName/Views/Shared/EditorTemplates` instead. There's also a Views/Shared/DisplayTemplates Equivalent for display templates.

Comment: check this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19247958/master-detail-create-views-with-razor-asp-net-mvc-3-and-net-4-0/19248361?noredirect=1#comment28499857_19248361

Answer (score 0):

Your Class Entity Name should match with the Name of the Template
Eg: If your ADO.net Employee entity name is "Employee" then the name of the template should be "Employee.cshtml" in Shared folder under Views directory